# Get direct child elements with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get only direct child elements with getElementsByClassName. Now I have e.g. this HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

And I only want the two div which is direct childs to div with "parent" class name.

```
const parentElement = ...
const contents = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('content');
console.log(contents); // returns three elements
```

Comment: Why not using `document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .content')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` instead, and use the selector string `.parent > .content` to select `.content`s which are *direct children* of `.parent`:

```js
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .content');
console.log(contents.length);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

If your HTML has more than one parent, and you only want to select the children `.content` of a single parent, then select that parent, call `querySelectorAll` on *it* (instead of the document), and use `:scope > .content`:

```js
const contents = first.querySelectorAll(':scope > .content');
console.log(contents.length);
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="first">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children` property

```js
const contents = document.querySelector('.parent').children;
console.log(contents); // returns two elements
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then I probably would get all the children? I did not write a third div with e.g. `.another-type-of-content` as class name, which I would like to not be included.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives without using css selectors could be:

```js
// Get the first element with class .container
const el = Array.from(parent.children).find(el => el.classList.contains('container'));

// Check existence of a child with class .container
const isExist = Array.from(parent.children).some(el => el.classList.contains('container'));

// Get all elements with class .container
const els = Array.from(parent.children).filter(el => el.classList.contains('container'));
```

These are more performant than other alternatives if you already have access to the parent element because you look into direct children not all descendents.